# Mysql Query Displays an error in SQL syntax when it's right

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax

I got sick of this error. I'm pretty sure it works with '$_POST[name]' but sql doesn't accept it.

It gives me the error saying: ***You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 2***

```
$syn = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['syn']);
$fore = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fore']);
 $localfore = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['localfore']);
$save = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tblforecast (Issued,Valid,Synopsis,Forecast,Local_Forecast,Station11,Station12,Station13,Station14,Station15,Station16,Station17,Station18,Station19,Forecaster)
                           VALUES (now(),'24','$syn','$fore','$localfore','sample','$sample','sample','sample','sample','sample','sample','sample','sample',$id)");
```

What's going on?

PS. Line 2 points at the start of *VALUES*

Comment: You should check  each $_POST data by isset()

Comment: oh yes. isset is working. this code is under isset :)

Comment: i tried to put VALUES within the line of $save and the error moved to line 1 (instead of 2) that is why I figured out the error points to that phrase

Comment: you have $sample] in values. That is not rightly formated

Comment: Instead of `'$_POST[syn]'` Try like `.$_POST['syn']`

Comment: Can you dump '$id' to see what's its value?
It may be null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tblforecast (Issued,Valid,Synopsis,Forecast,Local_Forecast,Station11,Station12,Station13,Station14,Station15,Station16,Station17,Station18,Station19,Forecaster)
                                   VALUES ('{$datetime}',24,'{$_POST[syn]}','{$_POST[fore]}','{$_POST[localfore]}','sample','sample','sample','sample','sample','sample','sample','sample','sample',$id)";
echo sql;

$save = mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: @Sarah : Can you run the output of $sql in your sql server and let me know what error you are getting?

Comment: it doesn't display anything actually. i meant it for saving. but i tried **if(!($save)) echo mysql_error();**, it displays that error

Comment: @Sarah : I have print sql query. You need to copy that query and run it in your sql server client

Comment: im using phpmyadmin. is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes run this query in your phpmyadmin.

Comment: ooohh i see... it's working now. i just cleared my cache. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is very bad practice to save post data directly. Instead you can use `$syn = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['syn']);` and `$syn` put into your sql query.

Comment: Hi! I updated my code. I have used your method but it now displays the error "check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''2014-01-03 16:03:57',24,'
VALUES ('$datetime',24,'$_POST[syn]'' at line 2" but i think there's still nothin wrong

Answer (score 0):

If you write the query in a more eadable way, you can spot some mistakes:

```
INSERT INTO
    tblforecast
(
    Issued
    ,Valid
    ,Synopsis
    ,Forecast
    ,Local_Forecast
    ,Station11
    ,Station12
    ,Station13
    ,Station14
    ,Station15
    ,Station16
    ,Station17
    ,Station18
    ,Station19
    ,Forecaster
) VALUES (
    '$datetime'
    ,24
    ,'$_POST[syn]'
    ,'$_POST[fore]'
    ,'$_POST[localfore]'
    ,'sample'
    ,'$sample]' // <-- is that supposed to be there?
    ,'sample'
    ,'sample'
    ,'sample'
    ,'sample'
    ,'sample'
    ,'sample'
    ,'sample'
    ,$id // <-- where are the closing brackets?
```

Comment: Hi! I accidentally placed a "]" upon typing it in. I updated my code btw :)